list the code path for Spark to write to the disk
Is there an official document that can exhaustively list the code paths for Spark to write to disk, such as shuffle, checkpoint, persistence, and other code blocks with disk writing actions?
I tried to exhaustively list all the code paths for writing disks in Spark. Used for my secondary development of writing disk operations on Spark
